# "Apply filter" or "apply filters"

Tags: phrase-requests, technology

In a search user interface for an application a whole bunch of settings can be used to create a filter. A button with a label is meant to kick off the processing using the filter defined by multiple key/value pairs.

Is the correct way to label the button *Apply Filter* (singular) or *Apply Filters* (plural)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label could simply say, "Filter" or "Filter Results."

You could conceptualize the different settings as being stages of a multi-element filter, so "Apply Filter" would be appropriate.

(Or, you could apply the settings [interactively](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/TableFilter) and dispense with the button altogether.)

Comment: I cant change it to Filter or Filter Results since that would have to go lots of translations and I cant interactively filter since it is a mobile app and the cost of loading it is too high. So in your opionion "Apply Filters" is incorrect right?

Comment: "Apply Filters" is not incorrect; it's just not necessary if you think of the different settings as being part of an overall filter. And it might be easier to translate than "Apply Filter(s)"

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from taking a look at Microsoft's user experience guidelines for applications, which has a thorough discussion of text, including capitalization. [[link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa974176.aspx#capitalization)